# Autolayout: Adjust view height based on newly set constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout

I just started using **AutoLayout** more thoroughly, and I encountered a big problem:

I have a view with some subviews attached to its **top** and some subviews attached to its **bottom**, so when the view is changed in height the subviews are moved accordingly. Depending on user actions the **height of the subviews can change** (= their height constraint values change), and this can lead to a situation where they don't fit in their parent view anymore.

**How can I find out whether a new set of constraints will make it necessary to change the parent view's height** in order to accommodate all of its subviews? Preferably before I display all fields with the new constraints - I'd like the view's height to change at the same time. Reason for this: I animate the change of constraint values, and I'd like to animate the view height change at the same time. Already performing the new constraints by calling `layoutIfNeeded` is out of the question because of this.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear enough, but couldn't you just get the height of each subview and compare the summary value with parent view's height?

Comment: I don't know the height of the subviews, because their height is calculated automatically by iOS via the constraints. Eg a textfield will automatically adapt its height according to its content, all views connected to this field will move downwards according to the vertical distance constraints etc. All this is provided *for free* with auto layout, so I'd rather not do all the calculations myself next to it.

Comment: Could you tell me what views do you have in parent view or make a screenshot?